# DateTime field value inside the SharePoint remote event receiver is different than the one the user enters

Tags: iis, sharepoint, azure-web-app-service

I am working on an online SharePoint site collection, which have the following regional settings:-

[image]

and I hosted a remote event receiver inside azure web app,where the remote event receiver will get fired when adding/updating list item. now inside the remote event receiver i have the following code to get a DateTime value named ApproveDate:-

```
DateTime approveBy = (DateTime)projectItem["ApproveDate"];
```

but if the user enter a value for the ApproveDate equal let say `30/09/2020` inside the SharePoint form as follow:-

[image]

then the DateTime value inside the remote event receive will be `9/29/2020 8:00:00 PM` instead of `9/30/2020 00:00:00 AM`.. so why i am facing this issue? is this because the azure web service have different time zone compared to the SharePoint site? and how i can fix this?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is no problem.

Assuming that the time zone of our web application server `IIS` is UTC time, then the parameter time passed by your SharePoint is `9/30/2020 00:00:00 AM`, and the `IIS` server time to the web should be minus 4 hours. The time stored by the IIS server is correct. When the front end needs to return, it is UTC+4 hours.

For our program, we should get the parameters of the Sharepoint part of the front-end page, such as time zone and other information, and then we can do the corresponding processing in the code when we return.

Comment: so you mean i need to check the time zone of the azure web service and then convert the time to be the same as the time zone of the sharepoint site?

Comment: now in my case the azure web app is hosted inside UK West location